# Passing over $O_K \otimes_{\mathbb{Z}} A$ from $O_K$, how it affects the rank of a module?

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, nt.number-theory, ac.commutative-algebra

This question was asked in [MSE](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4098760/compare-the-rank-of-the-module-m-over-the-different-rings-o-k-and-o-k-otim?noredirect=1#comment8473924_4098760) as well.

Let $K$ be a finite extension of the rationals $\mathbb{Q}$ with $O_K$ its the ring of integers.

Consider a $\mathbb{Z}$-algebra $A$ such that $|A|<\infty$.

Consider a module $M$ over the ring $O_K \otimes_{\mathbb{Z}} A$ and so $M$ is a module over $O_K$ also. We assume $M$ is $A$-flat as well.

My question is really about the ranks of $M$ over the different $3$ rings: More clearly, let

\begin{align}
r_1&:=\text{rank}_{O_K \otimes_{\mathbb{Z}} A}(M), \\ r_2&:=\text{rank}_{O_K}(M), \\r_3&:=\text{rank}_{ A}(M)
\end{align}
I want to understand relation between the ranks $r_1,~r_2,~r_3$  of the module $M$ over the rings $O_K \otimes_{\mathbb{Z}} A$, $O_K $ and $A$ respectively.

$(1)$ What is the relation among $r_1,~r_2,~r_3$ ?

$(2)$ Is $r_1=r_2=r_3$ or $r_1=r_3$ or $r_1=r_2$ ?

$-------$

Clearly $O_K$ being an integral domain, the $O_K$-rank of $M$ is equal to the $K$-vector space dimension of $(K \otimes_{O_K}M)$, where $K:=\text{Qout}(O_K)$ is the fraction field or quotient field of $O_K$, i.e.,
$r_2=\text{rank}_{O_K}(M)=\text{dim}_K(K \otimes_{O_K}M)=n$, say.

What about $r_1$ and $r_3$ ?

If we additionally assume that $A$ is finite flat $\mathbb{Z}$-algebra, does anything change ?

Assume that $A$ makes $O_K \otimes_{\mathbb{Z}} A$ an integral domain. Then what can we say about $O_K \otimes_{\mathbb{Z}} A$-rank of $M$, provided the $O_K$-rank of $M$ is $n$   ?

Any discussion or comments are welcome.  I just want to know how does it affect the rank of $M$ passing from $O_k$ to $O_K \otimes_{\mathbb{Z}}A$ ?

Thanks

Comment: Also at [MSE](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4098760/compare-the-rank-of-the-module-m-over-the-different-rings-o-k-and-o-k-otim). When crossposting, it's important to link all the versions of your question together to prevent duplicating work.

Comment: What does $|A|<\infty$ mean? Cardinality? If so, isn't $A$ a torsion module over $O_K$?

Comment: @Mohan, It means $A$ has finitely many elements. Ok, assume $A$ is flat $\mathbb{Z}$-algebra

Comment: One of the difficulties here is that $\mathcal O_K \otimes A$ may not be an integral domain. Its spectrum is connected if the same holds for $\operatorname{Spec} A$, but this is nontrivial. When $\operatorname{Spec} \mathcal O_K \otimes A$ is disconnected, what do you mean by rank? (A flat module can have different ranks on the different components.)

Comment: @R.vanDobbendeBruyn, I am basically trying to understand  the ranks of $M$  over the rings $O_K$ and $O_K \otimes_{\mathbb{Z}} A$. When are they same ? Assume $O_K \otimes_{\mathbb{Z}} A$ is also an integral domain, for example. Now suppose $O_K$-rank of $M$ is given,  then what can we say about $O_K \otimes_{\mathbb{Z}} A$-rank of $M$  ?

Comment: Then $\operatorname{rk}_{\mathcal O_K} M = \operatorname{rk}_{\mathcal O_K \otimes A} M \cdot \operatorname{rk}_{\mathbf Z} A$, since $\mathcal O_K \otimes A$ is flat of rank $\operatorname{rk}_{\mathbf Z} A$ over $\mathcal O_K$. (These ranks are just dimensions of the generic fibres.)

Comment: Your edits make it worse. No flat $\mathbb{Z}$ algebra can have finitely many elements.

Comment: @Mohan, Ok, we can assume $A$ to be finite flat $\mathbb{Z}$-algebra, which I mentioned 3rd line from the bottom. Here whenever I say finite flat it means $A$ is finitely  generated over $\mathbb{Z}$ both as algebra as well as module.

Comment: Then $A$ as a $\mathbb Z$-module is $\mathbb Z^r$ for some $r$, which means $\mathcal O_K \otimes_{\mathbb Z} A$ is $\mathcal O_K^r$, and hence the ranks are multiplied by $r$.

Comment: @R.vanDobbendeBruyn, Your comment is helping me but I don't have good concept on generic fibre (or points) and its dimensions. Can you please elaborate your discussion inform of a answer ? Since $A$ is $\mathbb{Z}$-algebra, there is a morphism  $f: \text{Spec}(A) \to \text{Spec}(\mathbb{Z})$ between schemes, then generic fibre over any fibre point $\mathfrak{p} \in \text{Spec}(\mathbb{Z})$ is $\text{Spec}(A) \otimes_{\text{Spec}(\mathbb{Z})} \text{Spec}(\kappa(\mathfrak{p})$. But how tofind its dimension ?

Comment: @WillSawin, Thank you very much for your nice input. So if $O_K$-rank of $M$ is $n$, say, then $O_K \otimes_{\mathbb{Z}} \mathbb{Z}^r=O_K^r$-rank of $M$ is $n/r$. Is it ?

Comment: If it's well-defined, yes. It might not be locally free of constant rank over $\mathcal O_K \otimes_{\mathbb Z} A$.